# Error at setFile to a QFileInfoList with a QString

Tags: c++, qt, assert, qlist

Lets assume I have:

```
QList<QString> filenameList;
```

filenameList has the paths to some files.

Then I create a QFileInfoList

```
QFileInfoList fileInfoList;
```

How can I use .setFile method for every object in the fileInfoList?
I tried:

```
for(int i=0;i<filenameList.length();i++)
 {

    fileInfoList[i].setFile(filenameList[i]);
 }
```

But I get this error after trying the program(it compiles succesfully).

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range"
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*fileInfoList* is empty when you try to access the first element of the list. What you want to do is replace the call to setFile with

```
fileInfoList.append(QFileInfo(filenameList[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing C++, not C, direct iteration over list elements using indices is a bit backwards-looking and error prone. `std::copy` or at least range-for are your friends.

You could use the following helper function:

```
// standard algorithms
QFileInfoList fileInfoListFromPaths(const QStringList & list) {
  QFileInfoList result;
  result.reserve(list.size());
  std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
  return result;
}

// explicit iteration
QFileInfoList fileInfoListFromPaths(const QStringList & list) {
  QFileInfoList result;
  result.reserve(list.size());
  #if 1
  // C++11
  for (path : list) result << QFileInfo(path);
  #else
  // or C++98
  foreach (path, list) result << QFileInfo(path);
  #endif
  return result;
}
```